# How tun run 2 seperate tf.keras models in a single program one on CPU and another on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a deep neural network model, -let's call it MODEL A- using tf.keras on my main train script, train.py.
This train.py imports utils.py where a data generator that feeds the training process is defined.
utils.py also imports other_utils.py where a pre-trained deep NN model -MODEL B- is created and initialized, because data generator uses it to process the training data.

Initialization of MODEL B already uses most of the GPU memory, leaving me with scarce sources to train MODEL A.

Import schema looks like:

```
train.py (MODEL A) --> utils.py (data generator) --> other_utils.py (MODEL B)
```

So I would like to run MODEL B on CPU and generate data, and train MODEL A on GPU.

In order to prevent MODEL B from using GPU, I tried setting environment variable on other_utils.py

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

then set it back on utils.py and train.py and then import tensorflow

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
import tensorflow
```

while setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = -1 disables GPU for MODEL B, it also disables GPU for further use and setting it back to CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0 on train.py and then importing tensorflow does not enable it back.

So how do I use MODEL B on CPU and MODEL A on GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu?hl=en) to implement my program.

Execute on CPU:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

    print(c.device)
```

Output:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

Execute on GPU:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

    print(c.device)
```

Output:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

Although, for anyone that will use a pre-trained within a data generator to train another model, I must say that preventing the pre-trained model from using GPU did not provide me additional speed-up for GPU training.